# Decimal Parse is throwing exception after changing NumberFormat Seperator in Global Thread

Tags: c#, globalization, cultureinfo, number-formatting, currentculture

```
   I have changed Global Application Culture thread for currency number format in (fr-CA) as shown below. 

Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyPositivePattern = 1;
                                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyNegativePattern = 5;

                            CultureInfo CADCultureref = new CultureInfo("fr-CA");
                            CADCultureref = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                            NumberFormatInfo CADNumFormatref = new NumberFormatInfo();
                            CADNumFormatref = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;

                            CADNumFormatref.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
                            CADNumFormatref.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
                            CADCultureref.NumberFormat = CADNumFormatref;
                            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CADCultureref;
                            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CADCultureref;
```

Then I try to parsing value from currency as shown below:

```
Decimal digit = 1000000;
String currency = digit.ToString("C"); //  1.000.000,00$ (fr-CAD)
decimal parseValue = decimal.Parse(currency , System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency | System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number);
```

I am getting exception "{Input String is not in correct format}" during parsing value.

Unable to parse due to changing in group seperator and decimal seperator in Numberformatinfo of CurrentThread.

I need to show "," in place of "." and  "." in place of ",".

Comment: Where does this code come from? If you put some code in your question, please put actual code that compiles.

Comment: I don't know what language it is, but certainly not C#.

Comment: It probably needs to be pointed out that the French play Monopoly with euros, not dollars.

Comment: I again update my question. Let me know is it understandable now?

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what your problem is, but it is generally better to explicitly pass culture information/number format into formatting and parsing functions like:

```
var  numberFormat = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;
numberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator  = ",";
numberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator  = ".";
Console.WriteLine(400000.ToString("C", numberFormat)); // Output: $ 4.000,00   
Console.WriteLine(
    decimal.Parse(400000.ToString("C", numberFormat),
           NumberStyles.Currency | NumberStyles.Number, 
           numberFormat));
```